# IIS default website to handle 404 and proxy it to a different website

Tags: asp.net, iis, proxy, web-config, http-status-code-404

Normally, when no web application is found, my Default Website returns `404`. But instead, in this case, I want the request to fall to the Default website `web.config`.

I have added my modules there which will handle the unknown request and will proxy it to a different website on a different server. How can I make this possible?

For example, my front end IIS can handle requests like this: `https://mywebsite/known-webapp/` as I have added a `webapplication` with name `"known-webapp"` under Default Website. However, when a request like this - `http://mywebsite/unknown-webapp` comes in, I want the request to fall back to the Default Website `web.config` and be caught by my modules and then proxied back to a different website and server (Backend). If the Backend returns `404`, only then it should return `404` to the user.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean you want to redirect users to another site when 404 error occurred in your web site? If this is the case, you can add the following markup to your application's Web.config file:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

then in your 404 web page, you can handle the redirection as you want.